# grids Visibility binded to a TabControl SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two grids contained in borders like this :

```
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=tcAction, Converter={StaticResource LoadChangeHeaderToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Grid x:Name="actionGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text=" Card Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" FontSize="16"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CardName}" FontSize="14"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ActionType, StringFormat='Action Type: {0}'}" Margin="4" FontSize="13" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Action, StringFormat='Action: {0}'}"  Margin="4" FontSize="13" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=tcAction, Converter={StaticResource LoadChangeHeaderToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Grid x:Name="actionCANGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text=" CAN Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" FontSize="16"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CardName}" FontSize="14"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ActionType, StringFormat='Action Type: {0}'}" Margin="4" FontSize="13" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Action, StringFormat='Action: {0}'}"  Margin="4" FontSize="13" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
```

Both of them are binded to the SelectedItem property of a TabControl. The fact here is that i want only one grid visible at a time, depending on the TabItem selected. So when Visibility is Visible for one of them, it should be Hidden for others. I am not sure how can i track the states of all the future grids, and keep only 1 in the front.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't mess with Visibility at all. That's the old WinForms way :)

Instead, I'd use a `ContentControl` and switch the `ContentTemplate` property in a `DataTrigger` based on the `SelectedItem`. I find this easier to maintain, and there's only one set of items in the visual tree at a time.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ActionTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ActionCANTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the SelectedItem of the tabcontrol, Bind SelectedIndex and pass the convertParamereter to the Converter

Your Converter will be like below

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value == (int)parameter)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

And in your Xmal change the visibility as below

```
Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=tcAction, Converter={StaticResource LoadChangeHeaderToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}">
```